# React animate leaving div content

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-spring

I'm using React and React-Spring to animate a questionnaire app.
I want the questionnaire to animate the leaving/enter of a question when the user answer one.

I'm using React for the app and try to use React-Spring to animate the transitions. The issue is that when the user is answering a question, the question component is updated with the new content before it leaving.

To simplify it, the Question component look like this:

```js
export default function Question({question, onAnswer}) {
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(null);
    return (
        <animated.div ...>
            {question.title}
            <select>...{quesiton.options}...</select>
            <button onClick={() => onAnswer(question.id, answer)}>Next</button>
        </animated.div>
    );
}
```

I create a Code Sandbox that illustrates my issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-swartz-lhkj0?file=/src/AnimatedComponent.js

How should I handle this? couldn't find any example on the web

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the item property in the transition map instead of using the text directly in the animated.div.

```
  {transitions.map(
    ({ item, key, props }) =>
      item && (
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          {item}
        </animated.div>
      )
  )}
```